# finding tcp version

Tags: macos, tcp

How can I find the version of TCP running on my MacOsX?

Comment: Inside Your program? If not this should go to superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

It's version 4. TCP version 3 was phased out in 1981 (!) and there's no version 5 yet.

[edit]And to make this a programming answer, call [getRandomNumber()](http://xkcd.com/221/)

Comment: Thanks, but I meant TCP REno, Fast TCP, etc. I meant TYPE of tcp implemented.